# Bash -Convert string to list of string

Tags: bash, shell

In a bash i would like to convert string to list of strings , like below

Input: a,b,c
Expected Output: ["a","b","c"]

Can someone please assist me with my query ?

Comment: What should happen to `"` in the input?

Comment: By "list of strings" you mean JSON? (Your sample output looks like JSON) Or a bash array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter expansion.

```sh
input=a,b,c
echo '["'"${input//,/'"','"'}"'"]'
```

It outputs:

```
'["' "${input//,/'"','"'}" '"]'
 ["       |                 "]
          |
          v
     here, each comma
     is replaced by ","
```

Answer (score 1):

Since JSON was brought up in a comment, another way using `jq`:

```sh
$ echo "a,b,c" | jq -Rc 'split(",")'
["a","b","c"]
```